# where should i keep my default image while gplus share..?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

```
<a><img onmouseover="bigImg(this)"onmouseout="normalImg(this)" src="icons/google-
plus.png"onclick="plus();" width="24" height="24" style="padding: 3px;cursor: 
pointer;"> </a>


function plus() {
var w = 500, h = 500;
var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
var post = window.location + '';
console.log('post = ' + post);
return window.open('https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=' +url_post,
+url_post, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no,  
scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' +  
top + ', left=' + left); }
```

I need to show my default image in this Google Plus share inside the Description area but its shows GO-To top image when I share my property. please any one help me?

result shows here : http://jsfiddle.net/rawoofpm/cL0n93rL/embedded/result/
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google+ API has [documented markup](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) for specifying what the preferred image should be. You will want to change aqarworld.com to include markup like this on every page.

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Shiny Trinket</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="{image-url}" />
  <p itemprop="description">Shiny trinkets are shiny.</p>
</body>
```